# Pull Twitter Posts into Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, twitter, google-apps-script, twitter-api

I would like to set-up a Google Spreadsheet that automatically pulls Twitter search results into the cells. For instance, I'd like to search for "pizza" near "baltimore" and then have any pizza mentions near baltimore populate into my Google Spreadsheet.

Twitter has changed their API a couple times. I haven't found anything that works.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You have to build it yourself. For all the recent changes in Twitter API, most developers are leaving this platform. Chances are very less that someone would build this now.

Comment: is posible, using tags... look at this > http://mashe.hawksey.info/2013/02/twitter-archive-tagsv5/

Answer (score 2):

[EDIT Disclosure: This answer is written by the TAGS author and includes links to his personal blog]

The Twitter Archiving Spreadsheet Template (TAGS) template mentioned in the question comments is one solution that has been continually developed to address Twitter API changes. [This post](http://mashe.hawksey.info/2013/02/twitter-archive-tagsv5/) will direct you to the latest version, alternatively [Open this Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AqGkLMU9sHmLdGdjakQzeE9GYU05ZFhlVWEwRjJIblE) and File > Make a copy and follow the setup instructions on the Readme/Setting sheet.

[The spreadsheet template has been used for a number of visualisation/analysis tools including [TAGSExplorer](http://hawksey.info/tagsexplorer/) and [TAGSViewer]](https://github.com/mlaa/tags-viewer) as well as tutorials such as '[Twitter Data for Really Targeted Outreach](http://moz.com/blog/how-to-use-twitter-data-for-really-targeted-outreach)' and [combining with Google Analytics referral data](http://bigdataweek.com/2012/12/12/google-apps-and-big-data/)]